# pass lambda as a delegate to method

Tags: c#, delegates

Im new in c# and I'm very confused over delegates. I know we should use them once we need to pass  same signatures methods with different condition to a method.

I have a class:

```
public class Turbines
{
    public string Turname { get; set; }
    public double TurID { get; set; }

    public double Production { get; set; }

    public double Availability { get; set; }
}
```

I initialize this class:

```
List<Turbines> newTur = new List<Turbines>
{
    new Turbines { Turname="inUK", TurID=1245, Production=1452.22, Availability=52.12 },
    new Turbines { Turname="InUS", TurID=125, Production=1052.22, Availability=92.12 }
};
```

Now if I want to get Turnames with avalability>90% and next time Turnames with Production>1300, I can have a method and pass a delegate to it.

Can anyone tell me how to create a method and delegate?

Comment: Do you mean newTur.Where(t => t.Availability > 90.0 && t.Production > 1300) ?

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet for sake of understanding delegates better i would like you tell me how to create a method to pass those conditions seperatly

Comment: newTur is a List<T> which implements IEnumerable<T>, you can use extension methods for IEnumerable<T> such as Where to filter collection based on certain predicates passed using Func<T, bool>. For example var items = newTur.Where(item => *your predicate here)

Comment: @mrslt: OK, so you mean .Where(t => t.Availability > 90.0).Where(t => t.Production > 1300)? I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for

Comment: Take a look at the method signature for the LINQ `Where(...)` clause, other than that it's not clear what you are really asking here.

Comment: where is the delegate?i want to have a method and delegate with same signatures,

Comment: @mrslt I know it might look like I have an ulterior agenda or that it is spam but it isn't. I suggest you learn all about delegates first. Read an article. If you can't understand English, if you understand Hindi, here is a series of four short videos that might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh5quAsP1SU

Comment: From want you write there I see no clear indication why you would want a `delegate`. All we see is that you want a function with a `double` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `Predicate<Turbine>` delegate. This delegate represents a method with the following signature:

```
bool Method(Turbine turbine)
```

You should write a method like this:

```
public List<Turbine> GetTurbines(Predicate<Turbine> predicate) {
    var list = new List<Turbine>();
   foreach (var turbine in newTur) {
       if (predicate(turbine)) {
           list.Add(turbine);
       }
   }
   return list;
}
```

Note the part `if (predicate(turbine))`, there I am basically calling the method that is passed in. If the method returns true, I add it to the list.

So you could pass a method like this into `GetTurbines` to get all the turbines with availability over 90:

```
bool Over90Availability(Turbine turbine) {
   return turbine.Availability > 90;
}
// ...
var list = GetTurbines(Over90Availability);
```

You can rewrite the method with a lambda expression:

```
var list = GetTurbines(turbine => turbine.Availability > 90);
```

The word `turbine` before the `=>` is the parameter name. Everything after the `=>` is the value you return.

Hope you understand how this works now.

In fact, you have just reinvented the wheel by creating `GetTurbine`. There is an extension method called `Where` in `System.Linq.Enumerable` that is basically the same thing:

```
var list = newTur.Where(turbine => turbine.Availability > 90).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks but i dont understand the difference between predicate and Func and normal delegate,sorry the problem is with my understanding not your example

Comment: @mrslt `Predicate` and `Func` _are_ normal delegates. `Func<T, TResult>` represents a method that takes a `T` as parameter and returns something of type `TResult`. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Func<T,Tresult> by T here you mean the lamda expression and Tresult is the result i get out of it?could be string,list , ...?

Comment: @mrslt by `T` and `TResult` I mean any type. `Func` is a generic delegate. You know what are generics, right? Say, `Func<int, string>` represents a method that takes an `int` as a parameter returns a `string`. Lambda expressions don't have types per se, but they can be converted to compatible delegates. `x => x.ToString()` is a lambda expression that can be converted to `Func<int, string>`. You can invoke the delegate and this will be just like invoking a method. You need to pass in an `int`, and the returned value will be a `string`.

Comment: @mrslt Have you read the [delegates programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)?

Comment: yes i read,and predicate is a specific kind of Func which returns bool only

Answer (score 3):

Delegates are a way to pass methods (including lambdas) as parameters:

```
   var selection = MyFilter( newTur , t => t.Availability > 90);


IENumerable<Turbines> MyFilter(IENumerable<Turbines> source, Func<Turbines, bool> filter)
{
   return source.Where(filter);
}
```

Note that things become slightly more readable when you drop the `s` from `Turbines`. An object is a single `Turbine`.

And a lambda is just a way to write an in-line function. You can also call MyFilter like this:

```
 var selection2 = MyFilter( newTur , ProductionOver1300);


bool ProductionOver1300(Turbines t)  // matches  Func<Turbines, bool> 
{
   return t.Production > 1300;
}
```

The syntax is tricky, `bool b = ProductionOver1300(aTurbine)` is a nomal function call. Leave out the parameters to get a delegate: `Func<Turbines, bool> f = ProductionOver1300;` . `f` is now a delegate variable and you can do `bool b = f(aTurbine);`

Comment: I'd also suggest that "Turname" should just be "Name". It's the name of a turbine, not the turname of a turbine (I strongly suspect, anyway).

Comment: And `TurID` just `ID`. And `int`, not `double`... Or does @mrslt want fractional ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply apply this piece of code

```
var result = newTur.Where(each => each.Availability > 90 && each.Turnames > 1300);
```

Comment: The question asks how delegate works, not "write this LINQ for me". If you are not going to take the time to explain this wrong (wrong because the OP asks for availability OR turnames as different filters) answer, don't answer at all

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, so I will try to explain some basic concepts.

First of all, since you have a `List<Turbines>` and `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use the [`.Where` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx).
This method acts on an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, and takes as argument a predicate with the signature `Func<TSource, bool>`. You can pass this argument in several ways, the two more common being 1) with a lambda and 2) with a classic method:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {
        List<Turbines> newTur = new List<Turbines>
        {
            new Turbines { Turname = "inUK", TurID = 1245, Production = 1452.22, Availability = 52.12 },
            new Turbines { Turname = "InUS", TurID = 125, Production = 1052.22, Availability = 92.12 }
        };

        // 1) passing filter as a lambda
        IEnumerable<Turbines> filteredListWithLambda = newTur.Where(t => t.Availability > 90.0 && t.Production > 1300);

        // 2) passing filter as a method
        IEnumerable<Turbines> filteredListWithMethod = newTur.Where(Filter);
    }

    private bool Filter(Turbines turbines)
    {
        return turbines.Availability > 90.0 && turbines.Production > 1300;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the values of your filter, you will have have to receive in `YourMethod` these values, and plug them in the filter, like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public void YourMethod(double availability, int production)
    {
        List<Turbines> newTur = new List<Turbines>
        {
            new Turbines { Turname = "inUK", TurID = 1245, Production = 1452.22, Availability = 52.12 },
            new Turbines { Turname = "InUS", TurID = 125, Production = 1052.22, Availability = 92.12 }
        };

        IEnumerable<Turbines> filteredListWithLambda = newTur.Where(t => t.Availability > availability && t.Production > production);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to get 2 different results from the same collection (List) at 2 different times. The most basic way to do this would be define methods within that collection which would return you results, ex - one method which returns you results whose availability > 90% and another whose production > 1300. But by doing those, you are losing the dynamic nature of the request and making the collection heavy with methods - meaning everytime you need to change this criteria you need to modify the collection and add a new method.

To solve this problem, we have delegates - which said simply works like a function pointer. So, basically instead of writing new methods in the container, you are passing a piece of code as an object which determines which elements to select out of your collection. This approach is called "Inversion of Control".

So, here for availability, you call List.Where and pass it a function which tells it whether to include a particular Turbines object or not.

```
Func<Turbines, bool> availabilityFunc = delegate (Turbines t)
{
    return t.Availability > 90;
};
var result = newTur.Where(availabilityFunc);
```

The Where method is a filtering method which selects certain elements in the container based on the predicate which is passed. Here, the predicate is the Func type delegate - which basically is a function object within which I have encapsulated the selection logic.

Now instead of doing all this, you can simply pass a lambda expression as a shortcut.

```
var result = newTur.Where( t => t.Availability > 90; );
```